# Xamarin iOS pop complete UINavigationController from stack

Tags: xamarin.ios

I pretty new to Xamarin.iOS and I need some help on the navigation.

To make it short, here is how the navigation should work in my application:

My application consists of 3 screens.

**Screen 1 :**
This is a simple UITableViewController where I can add items to the list.
When I add an item I have a segue (show details) to screen 2.

**Screen 2 & 3:**
Screen 2 is embedded in a UINavigationController.
Screen 3 is the end of my wizzard to add an item.

On screen 3 when I'm done, I have a button to navigate back to Screen 1.
How do I navigate from there and remove from the stack the UINavigationController, Screen 2 & 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Xamarin docs: [Creating an Unwind Segue](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/storyboard/unwind_segue/)

An unwind Segue can be used to navigate back through a push or modal segue - for 
example by dismissing the modally presented view controller. In addition to this, you can unwind through not only one, but a series of push and modal segues and go back multiple steps in your navigation heirarchy with a single unwind action.

You just need this piece of code in the target UIViewController

```
[Action ("UnwindToTargetViewController:")]
public void UnwindToTargetViewController (UIStoryboardSegue segue)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("We've unwinded to Target!");
}
```

On the OriginViewController, just link a button with the exit scene and select the method you just created!

Answer (score 0):

use the [PopToRootViewController](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UINavigationController.PopToRootViewController/p/System.Boolean/)() method on UINavigationController

```
nav.PopToRootViewController(true);
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, actually, what I was looking for is an unwind segue